# GCC doesn't want to change output file

Tags: gcc, compilation

It seems that since I installed the latest version of GCC, I am no longer able to compile any C file if I want to change the output file. Let's take an example, file `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     printf("hello\n");
}
```

If I do :

```
gcc hello.c
```

It works fine and I have the `a.out` output. But if I want to change the name of the output, I should basically do :

```
gcc -o hello.c hello
```

Am I right?

If so, I get this error :

```
gcc: error: hello: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

For another example, it goes totally WTF :

```
gcc -o Simplexe.c Simplexe
Simplexe: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
Simplexe: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
Simplexe: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
Simplexe:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
Simplexe: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
Simplexe: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
Simplexe:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in Simplexe(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
```

I have never seen something like that, and it deleted my source file. I got caught once, I will never be anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
gcc -o hello.c hello
```

to

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

`-o` is followed by the target, not the source.

Your second case could occur, if the target `Simplexe` exists and now gcc tries to link this again into the "target" `Simplexe.c`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: This is right, Simplexe file exists, and this is why it did not work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

-o specified output file, which is **hello.c** in your case, so you are trying to compile file **hello**, which doesn't exist. Correct command would be:

> gcc hello.c -o hello

Comment: I feel so dumb, I was so sure of my command line -_-". Of course this is the solution. And yet I tried hard!